# FirebaseFirestore CRUD , throwing exceptions

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am basically trying CRUD on FirebaseFirestore, adding users are successful but deletion and updating user's info is throwing error:

The codebase is pretty straightforward. The add() is working as expected but the update() and delete()  are not showing the
desired results.

My code :

Adding user method -

```
 addUser() {
    User user = User(name: controller.text );
    try {
       FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async{
       await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(CollectionName).doc().set(user.toJson());
      },);
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
  add(){
    if(isEditing){
      update(curUser, controller.text);
      setState(() {
        isEditing = false;
      });
    }else{
      addUser();
    }
    controller.text = '';
  }
```

Deleting UserRecord -

```
 delete(User user){
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      transaction.delete(user.reference);
    },
    );
  }
```

Updating record -

```
  update(User user, String newName) {
    try {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
        await transaction.update(user.reference, {'name': newName});
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

The error that I am receiving :

```
   ════════ Exception caught by the gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Stack Overflow
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
W/h.crud_firebas( 5985): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
```